# Why CGI is not working in apache

Tags: linux, virtualhost, cgi, apache2

I have got url like this:

> http:// ipadress/project/cgi/sessionlogin.cgi?login=usernmae&password=somepass

but when I open this url I see download action of cgi file, not a results.
I have .htaccess in folder with cgi scripts (/var/www/html/project/cgi) with this info:

```
AllowOverride None
Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
#Order allow,deny
Require all granted
Allow from all
```

I also have this part in virtualhost config:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/var/www/html/project/cgi/"

<Directory "/var/www/html/project/cgi">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        #Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But it all stiill is not working. cgi module is enabled. 
This is C++ binary cgi files.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, setting [`AllowOverride None`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) means that any `.htaccess` file will be ignored (which is a good thing since you already have access to the main Apache VirtualHost config) so you might as well delete the `.htaccess` file.

Second the actual CGI file needs to have the correct permissions to be executable by Apache (`chmod 755`) and if you're running SELinux you might need to activate the `httpd_enable_cgi` SELinux boolean and ensure that the CGI file is labeled with `httpd_sys_script_exec_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Although my system is Apache24 on windows 8.1, i think this problem is more general regardless of systems. I had a working configuration with Apache22 on windows 7 and i did not do any remarkable change when upgrade to apache24 on windows 8.1. When i googled for this problem , i realize there is no general solution. Obviously Apache24 did not see my_file_extension as executable.

Moreover,although i cleared the firefox cache from "c:\users\appdata\local\temp" directory, and remove the file from disc; firefox constantly gave the same file from my file system (namely file:\\c:\users\appdata\local\temp\the-file). And this situation existed for each of my servers (one server on my main machine and server on the other test machine).

So the solution i found (i think more general, at least works for me) is using the "Module mod_actions" directive ("Action" Directive).

To sum up : 
My old configuration is like this

```
#for alias_module
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/"

# for cgi directory
# my_file_extension is ksp
<Directory   "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">  
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI 
  Require all granted       
  Addhandler cgi-script .ksp
</Directory>
```

and new configuration is like this

```
#for alias_module
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/"

# for cgi directory
# my_file_extension is ksp
<Directory   "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">  
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI 
  Require all granted           
</Directory>

# then the new directive i added;
# for any file in the server root directory that has an extension .ksp
<Location />     
  AddHandler ksp  .ksp
  Action ksp "/cgi-bin/CGI_KSP.exe"
</Location>
```

In the apache's documentation for Action directive, as an example

```
Example: File extension

# Files of a particular file extension
AddHandler my-file-type .xyz
Action my-file-type "/cgi-bin/program.cgi"

In this example, requests for files with a file extension of .xyz are handled by the specified cgi script /cgi-bin/program.cgi.
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether this would be something new in Apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04, but I had a problem where my executable would not start. Instead, Apache2 would offer me to download it.

It took me some time to find *"a work around"* (I think that's a huge bug in Apache2) which was to change the alias path.

This failed, no matter what:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/project/cgi-bin/
```

I used a unique name for my website like so:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi/ /var/www/project/cgi-bin/
```

And it works like a charm!!!

I'm thinking that there is a conflict between different `<VirtualHost ...>` using the same `ScriptAlias` or something like that. I've not been able to find the exact cause of this issue. But now my site works as expected.